# FFmpeg remove silence with exact duration detected by detect silence

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have an audio file, that have some silences, which I am detecting with ffmpeg detectsilence and then trying to remove with removesilence, however there is some strange behavior. Specifically:

**1)** File's Basic info based on ffprobe show_streams

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'my_file.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.64.100
  Duration: 00:00:25.22, start: 0.046042, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 24000 Hz, mono, fltp, 32 kb/s
```

**2)** Using detectsilence

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.2 -f null -
```

I get this result

```
[mp3float @ 000001ee50074280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -1 -1
[silencedetect @ 000001ee5008a1c0] silence_start: 6.21417
[silencedetect @ 000001ee5008a1c0] silence_end: 6.91712 | silence_duration: 0.702958
[silencedetect @ 000001ee5008a1c0] silence_start: 16.44
[silencedetect @ 000001ee5008a1c0] silence_end: 17.1547 | silence_duration: 0.714708
[mp3float @ 000001ee50074280] overread, skip -10 enddists: -3 -3
[mp3float @ 000001ee50074280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
[silencedetect @ 000001ee5008a1c0] silence_start: 24.4501
size=N/A time=00:00:25.17 bitrate=N/A speed=1.32e+03x
video:0kB audio:1180kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[silencedetect @ 000001ee5008a1c0] silence_end: 25.176 | silence_duration: 0.725917
```

That also match the values and points based on Adobe Audition

[image: my file adobe audition silences]

So far all good.

**3)** Now, based on some calculations (which is based on application's logic on what should be the final duration of the audio) I am trying to delete the silence with "0.725917"s duration. For that, based on ffmpeg docs (https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect)

> Trim all silence encountered from beginning to end where there is more
> than 1 second of silence in audio:
> silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_duration=1:stop_threshold=-90dB

I run this command

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.72 result1.mp3
```

So, I am expecting that it should delete only the silence with "0.725917" duration (the last one in the above image), however it is deleting the silence that starts at 16.44s with duration of "0.714708"s. Please see the following comparison:

[image: my file and result1 adobe audition silence comparison]

**4)** Running detectsilence on result1.mp3 with same options gives even stranger results

```
ffmpeg -i result1.mp3 -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.2 -f null -
```

result

```
[mp3float @ 0000017723404280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
[silencedetect @ 0000017723419540] silence_start: 6.21417
[silencedetect @ 0000017723419540] silence_end: 6.92462 | silence_duration: 0.710458
[mp3float @ 0000017723404280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -6 -6
[mp3float @ 0000017723404280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -2 -2
[mp3float @ 0000017723404280] overread, skip -6 enddists: -1 -1
    Last message repeated 1 times
[silencedetect @ 0000017723419540] silence_start: 23.7308
size=N/A time=00:00:24.45 bitrate=N/A speed=1.33e+03x
video:0kB audio:1146kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[silencedetect @ 0000017723419540] silence_end: 24.456 | silence_duration: 0.725167
```

**So, the results are:**

- With command to remove silences that are longer than "0.72 second", a silence that was "0.714708"s, got removed **and** - a silence with "0.725917"s remained as is (well, actually changed a little - as per 3rd point)
- The first silence that had started at "6.21417" and had a duration of "0.702958"s, suddenly now has a duration of "0.710458"s
- The 3rd silence that had started at "24.4501" (which now starts at 23.7308 - obviously because the 2nd silence was removed) and had a duration of "0.725917", now suddenly is "0.725167"s (this one is not a big difference, but still why even removing other silence, this silence's duration should change at all).

**Accordingly the expected results are:**

- Only the silences that match the provided condition (stop_duration=0.72) should be removed. In this specific example only the last one, but in general any silence that matches the condition of the length - irrelevant of their positioning (start, end or in the middle)
- Other silences should remain with same exact duration they were before

**FFMpeg:** 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1, **Ubuntu:** 20.04.2

**Some attempts and results, while playing with ffmpeg options**

**a)**

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.72:detection=peak tmp1.mp3
```

**result:**
First and second silences are removed, 3rd silence's duration remains exactly the same

**b)**

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.71 tmp_0.71.mp3
```

**result:**
First and second silences are removed, 3rd silence remains, but the duration becomes "0.72075"s

**c)**

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.7 tmp_0.7.mp3
```

**result:**
all 3 silence are removed

**d)** the edge case

this command still removes the second silence (after which the first silence become exactly as in point **#4** and last silence becomes "0.721375")

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.72335499999 tmp_0.72335499999.mp3
```

but this one, again does not remove any silence:

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.723355 tmp_0.723355.mp3
```

**e)** window param case 0.03

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.72:window=0.03 window_0.03.mp3
```

does not remove any silence, but the detect silence

```
ffmpeg -i window_0.03.mp3 -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.2 -f null -
```

gives this result (compare with silences in **result1.mp3** - from point **#4** )

```
[mp3float @ 000001c5c8824280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
[silencedetect @ 000001c5c883a040] silence_start: 6.21417
[silencedetect @ 000001c5c883a040] silence_end: 6.92462 | silence_duration: 0.710458
[mp3float @ 000001c5c8824280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -6 -6
[mp3float @ 000001c5c8824280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -2 -2
[silencedetect @ 000001c5c883a040] silence_start: 16.4424
[silencedetect @ 000001c5c883a040] silence_end: 17.1555 | silence_duration: 0.713167
[mp3float @ 000001c5c8824280] overread, skip -6 enddists: -1 -1
    Last message repeated 1 times
[silencedetect @ 000001c5c883a040] silence_start: 24.4508
size=N/A time=00:00:25.17 bitrate=N/A speed=1.24e+03x
video:0kB audio:1180kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[silencedetect @ 000001c5c883a040] silence_end: 25.176 | silence_duration: 0.725167
```

**f)** window case 0.01

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.72:window=0.01 window_0.01.mp3
```

removes first and second silences, the detect silence with same params has the following result

```
[mp3float @ 000001ea631d4280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3float @ 000001ea631d4280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -2 -2
[mp3float @ 000001ea631d4280] overread, skip -6 enddists: -1 -1
    Last message repeated 1 times
[silencedetect @ 000001ea631ea1c0] silence_start: 23.0108
size=N/A time=00:00:23.73 bitrate=N/A speed=1.2e+03x
video:0kB audio:1113kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[silencedetect @ 000001ea631ea1c0] silence_end: 23.736 | silence_duration: 0.725167
```

---

Any thoughts, ideas, points are much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample input file?

Comment: Have you tried tweaking `window=` and `detection=`?

Comment: @llogan here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rd8oopeicjam3sm/my_file.mp3?dl=0

Comment: @user3840170 yes in fact had tried a lot of different variations of pretty much all options (not all had documented to include in the post though) - but just edited the post to include 2 cases with window param. One case of detection param is the case a).

Comment: Is the goal to remove only end of file silences and ignore the others?

Comment: @llogan the goal is to remove only those silences that match the given condition (meaning longer than x seconds) - irrelevant of their positioning (start, middle or end) - so though in this example the silence is at the end, but in other cases the silence to be removed might be in the middle/at the beginning. (Updated the question to clarify that part in the post as well)

Comment: @dav  I updated my post over at the other ffmpeg question you were interesting in.  I ended up supplying a big python script that does a lot of the functionality being asked for.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910301/how-to-shorten-silence-in-audio-file-using-ffmpeg

Comment: @MarkH thanks, will check out and get back. And thanks a lot for this question's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're suffering from two things:

1. You are converting back to an mp3 (a lossy format), which is causing result1.mp3 to be reencoded and become *slightly* different than a perfect cut.  The fix for this is to use .wav's (a lossless format).
2. The silenceremove function is using a window and you need to set it to 0 to do sample-by-sample.

```
ffmpeg -i my_file.mp3 my_file.wav
ffmpeg -i my_file.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.2 -f null -
ffmpeg -i my_file.wav -af silenceremove=stop_periods=-1:stop_threshold=-50dB:stop_duration=0.72:window=0 result1.wav
ffmpeg -i result1.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-50dB:d=0.2 -f null -
```

Final output of the last line.  I would consider this a solid solution, because the silence starts and durations match up perfectly with their values before the cut:

```
[silencedetect @ 0x5570a855b400] silence_start: 6.21417
[silencedetect @ 0x5570a855b400] silence_end: 6.91712 | silence_duration: 0.702958
[silencedetect @ 0x5570a855b400] silence_start: 16.44
[silencedetect @ 0x5570a855b400] silence_end: 17.1547 | silence_duration: 0.714708
size=N/A time=00:00:24.45 bitrate=N/A speed=4.49e+03x
```

You can then reencode it to .mp3 if you want.